# C++ unique_ptr object access

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
class Table {
    int size = -99;
    string name = "Undefined";
    string type = "Undefined";
    string description = "Undefined";
public:
    int getSize() const {return size;}
    string getType() const {return type;}
    string getName() const {return name;}
    string getDescription() const {return description;}
    Table(int size = -99, string &&name = "Undefined", string &&type = "Undefined", string &&description = "Undefined");
    virtual string toString() const; //returns string as 'Name - Size - Type - ...'
};

class FurnitureStore {
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    int depth = 0;
    bool open = false; 
    unique_ptr<Table> ***tables;
}
```

Now I'm implementing FurnitureStore method, which loops trough ***tables and for every table gets a string value, from method toString(). Hovewer, I'm not sure how to create an access to object under unique_ptr:

```
int FurnitureStore<Table>::manage(Table &&table, int x, int y) {
    //...
    if (tables[x][y].operator*().toString() == ...) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Where tables[x][y].operator*().toString() doesn't work as intended. Did I make an error in my code?
Please note that I should keep structure of classes and attributes the same.

Comment: `unique_ptr<Table> ***tables;` seriously pointer to pointer to pointer? Explain what do you try to achieve, because I don't believe that you need a ptr ptr ptr of unique_ptr. Your syntax for dereferencing `tables` should be `tables[x][y][z]->toString()`, but as I mentioned, for sure you don't want it this way.

Comment: Wow. Four levels of indirection.

Comment: Another issue, why do you pass your arguments by rvalue reference? I don't think that your intention is to move them.

Comment: @pptaszni ...to a (unique) pointer...

Comment: `unique_ptr<Table> ***tables;` is the weirdest thing I’ve seen in a long time. I urge you to consider `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Table>> tables;`, with a helper function like `Table* get_table(int x, int y, int z){ return tables.at(x * height * depth + y * depth + z).get(); }`. It would save you many hours of debugging and many headaches

Comment: You probably want `unique_ptr<Table> **tables;` and access it with `tables[x][y]->toString()`. But that's provided it is actually structured as a 2D raw array.

Comment: Wrapping a unique_ptr in any number of layers of vanilla pointers defeats the purpose of having a unique_ptr in the first place.  A unique_ptr deletes itself, ***unique_ptr does not.  I'd also like to suggest following @alterigel's suggestion and further recommend `indexFromHeightWidthDepth()` and perhaps `heightWidthDepthFromIndex()` (for debugging purposes if nothing else).